How can I split up a text string in SQL that uses 'mm:dd:yyyy: ' as a delimiter?
In SQL I have a table field that shows a log of events in a call. It is formatted like:
HH:MM:SS: Call Initiated HH:MM:SS: Call answered HH:MM:SS: Menu Main HH:MM:SS: Menu Self Service HH:MM:SS: Member Premium HH:MM:SS: One Time Payment HH:MM:SS: Transfer to agent HH:MM:SS: Disconnected \[Remote Disconnect\]'

I am trying to get a column that breaks this out into a row for each section within that string, like:
HH:MM:SS: Call Initiated
HH:MM:SS: Call answered
HH:MM:SS: Menu Main
HH:MM:SS: Menu Self Service
HH:MM:SS: Member Premium
HH:MM:SS: One Time Payment
HH:MM:SS: Transfer to agent
HH:MM:SS: Disconnected \[Remote Disconnect\]

I have had some success using the STRING_SPLIT and replacing the multi character delimiter ': ' with a single character delimiter, but the results:
DECLARE @OLDdelim varchar(2)    = ': '
DECLARE @NEWdelim nchar(1)  = NCHAR(9999)

SELECT CallId,CallDate,value FROM calldetail cd
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(cd.CallEventLog, @OLDdelim, @NEWdelim), @NEWdelim)

CURRENT RESULTS (date for the next item is after the value of the current row)
CallId                  CallDate    value

100264416140230613  2023-06-13  06:07:53
100264416140230613  2023-06-13  Initializing 06:07:55
100264416140230613  2023-06-13  Offering 06:07:57
100264416140230613  2023-06-13  Call answered 06:08:14
100264416140230613  2023-06-13  Menu Main 06:08:17
100264416140230613  2023-06-13  Menu Self Service 06:08:21

DESIRED RESULTS
CallId                  CallDate        LogEventTime_Description

100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:07:53 Initializing
100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:07:55 Offering
100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:07:57 Call answered
100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:08:14 Main Menu
100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:08:17 Menu Self Service
100264416140230613      2023-06-13      06:08:21 Member Premium


Please tag your RDBMS, see here why that's important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms .
Oracle: REGEXP_SUBSTR and CONNECT BY,
SQL Server: STRING_SPLIT function,
MySQL: SUBSTRING_INDEX or JSON functions,
PostgreSQL: UNNEST and STRING_TO_ARRAY

I suspect you want to use SUBSTRING instead of STRING_SPLIT because you know how many characters each chunk requires.

Can you do it in a scripting language like php, python or javascript?  It would be much easier.

Bit of a hack but you might try lag():
with data as (
    select *,
        right(lag(value) over (partition by CallId order by ordinal), 8) as tm, 
        case when ordinal < max(ordinal) over (partition by CallId)
             then left(value, len(value) - 9) else value end as dtl
    from calldetail cross apply
        string_split(replace(calleventlog, ': ', '^'), '^', 1) ss
)
select * from data where ordinal > 1;

https://dbfiddle.uk/BmXjMw1d

;WITH CTE_X AS
(

SELECT [CallId],[CallDate],[Value1]=LEFT([Value],LEN([Value])-CASE WHEN [Value] LIKE '% %' THEN 9 ELSE 8 END),[Value]
FROMcalldetail

)

SELECT [CallId],[CallDate],
[LogEventTime_Description] = CONCAT(TRIM(REPLACE([Value],[Value1],'')),' ',[Value1])

FROM CTE_X


Please format your code so that it easy to read using the code formatting option in the editor

And please include an explanation in addition to code

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try split all and then aggregate back.
Split string to words - delimiter ' '(space).
Word like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:%' - first for separate event.
Calculate group number (grn) for every word by sum(...)over(...) .
Group by main columns and grn.
See example
select CallId,CallDate
  ,string_agg(value,' ') event
from(
  SELECT CallId,CallDate,value,ordinal
   ,sum(case when value like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:%' then 1 else 0 end)
    over(partition by CallId order by ordinal) grn
  FROM calldetail cd
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(cd.CallEventLog,' ',1)
 ) t
group by CallId,CallDate,grn
;

Fiddle
Before aggregating we have



CallId
CallDate
value
ordinal
f
grn




100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:07:53:
1
1
1


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Initializing
2
0
1


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:07:55:
3
1
2


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Offering
4
0
2


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:07:57:
5
1
3


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Call.
6
0
3


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
answered
7
0
3


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:08:14:
8
1
4


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Main
9
0
4


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Menu
10
0
4


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:08:17:
11
1
5


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Menu
12
0
5


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Self
13
0
5


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Service
14
0
5


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
06:08:21:
15
1
6


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Member
16
0
6


100264416140230613
2023-06-13
Premium
17
0
6



Ordinal for string_split is available for SQL Server since 2022. You my replace ordinal with  row_number().
 cross apply (select value,row_number()over(order by(select 1))ordinal 
  from STRING_SPLIT(cd.CallEventLog,' ')
)sw

